# System Extension Updated?

Tags: software-update, kernel-extensions, auto-update

Does Apple update system extensions without asking?

I was editing a LibreOffice spreadsheet when I was suddenly interrupted by
[image]

Even if legitimate, how am I supposed to know which one in the settings?

The last app store update was `SQLPro for SQLite.app` version 2024.10 updated about 24 hours ago.  The last O.S. update was macOS_14.2.1_23C71 on 3 Jan 2024.

An up-to-date MalwareBytes (free version) finds no malware.  SIP is enabled.

Settings shows me this:
[image]

Paragon is for NTFS, which I have no need of now.  The suggestion is that something from Apple was updated, but it is hard to believe that Apple would download something without the usual notification of "update available."  To the best of my knowledge, I have **never** agreed to automatic updates.

**Recommended action, if any?**

Comment: Apple does not do that